# Mathematica not evaluating #1

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I defined 2 objects:

```
f=x^2
g=x->#1
```

Why does this:

```
f /. x -> #1 &[5]
```

give me the expected result:

```
25
```

But this:

```
f /. g &[5]
```

gives me:

```
#1^2
```

As if the #1 wasn't evaluated to 5. 
Please help.

Comment: As so often with Mathematica, wrapping your expressions in Trace[] and examining the output is instructive here.

Comment: Thanks. But how could I modify the statement which gives me the wrong result to work as expected? I'm really a beginner in Mathematica so I don't know most things.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it work by keeping the pure function components together.

```
f = x^2
g = x -> #1 &

f/. g[5]
```

25

To run it over a list form the function before mapping.

```
f = x^2
g = x -> #1
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
b = Block[{a}, Function[f /. a] /. a -> g]
Map[b, list]
```

{1, 4, 9, 16, 25}

And for the specific problem in the comments...

```
vars = {x, y};
f = x + y;
g = Table[vars[[i]] -> Slot[i], {i, 1, Length[vars]}];
b = Block[{a}, Function[f /. a] /. a -> g];
list = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
Map[b[Sequence @@ #] &, list]
```

{3, 7, 11}

With Mr. Wizard's answer this can become:

```
vars = {x, y};
f = x + y;
g = Table[vars[[i]] -> Slot[i], {i, 1, Length[vars]}];
list = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
Map[Evaluate[f /. g] &[Sequence @@ #] &, list]
```

{3, 7, 11}

Comment: Okay, the problem is: Map[f /. {x -> #1} &, list]

Comment: Okay, the problem is, I'd like to do something like this: vars={x,y}; f=x+y; g=Table[vars[[i]] -> Slot[i], {i, 1, Length[vars]}]; list={{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}}; Map[f /. g &, list]; and get {5, 7, 11} This is because f would some expression from user and vars would be variable list so I can't hardcode the variables.

Comment: Great, thanks. One thing I don't understand: you send a Sequence to the block b. So the sequence is understood as parameter list for that block?

Comment: @ user1161552 - the function b expects input as a sequence, e.g. b[1,2] and will not accept a list like b[{1,2}]. Applying Sequence formats the input to b[1,2].  The Block is just used to shield 'a' in case 'a' was defined anywhere else, which would upset the replacement.

Comment: If you look at FullForm[b] you will see the Block has gone.

Comment: Can it be done without Block then (assuming a undefined)? Also, why is there & in Map[b[Sequence @@ #] &, list] ? b is a function so why does it need another &?

Comment: Yes, can omit the Block. The second pure function is to operate on the Map input, i.e. `Map[x, {1, 2}]` and `Map[x[#] &, {1, 2}]` are functionally the same, but the input on the latter can be processed as we did with `Sequence`.  Welcome to StackOverflow by the way.  There is a new Mathematica site here too: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 2):

[`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) (short form `&`) has attribute [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HoldAll.html):

```
Attributes[Function]
```

> ```
> {HoldAll, Protected}
> ```

Therefore `g` remains unevaluated.  You can force it with [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Evaluate.html):

```
Evaluate[f /. g] &[5]
```

> ```
> 25
> ```

`Evaluate` will not work deeper in the expression; you cannot write `f /. Evaluate[g] &`

Comment: Interesting - I didn't try wrapping the fuller expression in Evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `g=x->#1` with  `g=x->#1 &` and `f /. g &[5]` with `f/. g[5]`